# cbind() time series without NAs

Tags: r, time-series

I've observed that for many operators on overlapping time series, the result is given only for the overlapping portion, which is nice:

```
> (ts1 <- ts(1:5, start=1, freq=3))
Time Series:
Start = c(1, 1) 
End = c(2, 2) 
Frequency = 3 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> (ts2 <- ts((7:3)^2, start=2, freq=3))
Time Series:
Start = c(2, 1) 
End = c(3, 2) 
Frequency = 3 
[1] 49 36 25 16  9
> ts1 + ts2
Time Series:
Start = c(2, 1) 
End = c(2, 2) 
Frequency = 3 
[1] 53 41
```

However, this doesn't seem to be the case with `cbind()`.  While the output is aligned properly, `NA`s are created for the non-overlapping data:

```
> (mts <- cbind(ts1, ts2))
Time Series:
Start = c(1, 1) 
End = c(3, 2) 
Frequency = 3 
         ts1 ts2
1.000000   1  NA
1.333333   2  NA
1.666667   3  NA
2.000000   4  49
2.333333   5  36
2.666667  NA  25
3.000000  NA  16
3.333333  NA   9
```

Is there a way to perform that `cbind()` without creating the rows with `NA` in them?  Or if not, what's a good way to take the result and strip off the rows with the `NA`s?  It's not a simple matter of subscripting, because then it loses its timeseries nature:

```
> mts[complete.cases(mts),]
     ts1 ts2
[1,]   4  49
[2,]   5  36
```

Maybe something with `window()`, but calculating the start & end times for the window seems a little yucky.  Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just `na.omit` the result?

```
> na.omit(cbind(ts1,ts2))
Time Series:
Start = c(2, 1) 
End = c(2, 2) 
Frequency = 3 
         ts1 ts2
2.000000   4  49
2.333333   5  36
```

If you want to avoid `na.omit`, `stats:::cbind.ts` calls `stats:::.cbind.ts`, which has a `union` argument.  You could set that to `FALSE` and call `stats:::.cbind.ts` directly (after creating appropriate arguments):

```
> stats:::.cbind.ts(list(ts1,ts2),list('ts1','ts2'),union=FALSE)
Time Series:
Start = c(2, 1) 
End = c(2, 2) 
Frequency = 3 
         ts1 ts2
2.000000   4  49
2.333333   5  36
```

But the `na.omit` solution seems a tad easier. ;-)

Comment: Brilliant!  I didn't know `na.omit` could be called like that, thanks.

Comment: In fact I'm also happy to see the `stats:::.cbind.ts` version, because for large time series it can take a while to do the `na.omit` step.